# Heidi SQL -Laragon

Tags: heidisql, laragon

How to find the portable Heidi SQL server name?

Comment: HeidiSQL is a client, so you mean the database server name? And how can a server name be portable?

Comment: yes i mean the database server name, the name is Heidi portable.

Comment: Portable or not portable doesn't matter for HeidiSQL. If you installed _MySQL or MariaDB_ on your local system, then use `localhost` as servername.

Comment: sqlcmd -S localhost -d tutorials -E -Q "select * from tutorials.contacts" -s "," -o "C:\Users\Contact_query.txt"

Comment: Does your comment contain a new question, or is that an answer to your own question? Please write in whole sentences. Perfect english is not required, but others should somehow understand you.

Comment: @ANSE       sqlcmd -S localhost -d tutorials -E -Q "select * from tutorials.contacts" -s "," -o "C:\Users\Contact_query.txt"     this is my command but the batch file in not creating the existing text file

Comment: yes this is the command i used including the localhost as my server name but still it didn't do anything

Comment: `sqlcmd` is a command line utility for Microsoft SQL Server. I recommend having a look into [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2014) for your command line arguments.